# Sending JSON to Spring MVC - Error 415

Tags: jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send JSON from a form to a spring mvc controller, but i'm always getting error 415. 

I have already tried changing headers, types, stringify and etc. as said in other posts, without success. 

Could someone help? I'm new in this and still trying to understand.

Main page function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ConvertFormToJSON(form) {
    var array = jQuery(form).serializeArray();
    var json = {};

    jQuery.each(array, function() {
        json[this.name] = this.value || '';
    });

    return json;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#novoitem').submit(function() {

        var form = this;
        var json = ConvertFormToJSON(form);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
        jQuery.ajax({
            dataType : "json",
            contentType : "application/json",
            type : "POST",
            url : "inventario/",
            data : JSON.stringify(json),
            contentType : "application/json",
            success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Form:

```
<form id="novoitem" method="post" enctype='application/json'>
    <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label> 
    <input id="usuario" name="usuario" type="text">
    <label for="tipo">Tipo:</label>
    <input id="tipo" name="tipo" type="text">
    <label for="nomeItem">Item:</label>
    <input id="nomeItem" name="nomeItem" type="text">
    <label for="quantidade">Quantidade:</label>
    <input id="quantidade" name="quantidade"type="text">
    <label for="vencimento">Vencimento:</label>
    <input id="vencimento" name="vencimento" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Incluir">
</form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/inventario/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> insereItem(@RequestBody Item item){...}
```

Console.log Stringify:

```
{"usuario":"a","tipo":"b","nomeItem":"c","quantidade":"d","vencimento":"e"}
```

Error:

```
POST http://localhost:8888/inventario/ 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

Comment: replace : url : "inventario and @RequestMapping(value = "/inventario", method = RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: Solved by just putting all 3 jackson jars on classpath

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a MediaType in your request mapping in your controller like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/inventario/",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, 
                method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> insereItem(@RequestBody Item item){...}
```

Comment: I had to add like below, but still error 415
    
@RequestMapping(value = "/inventario", consumes = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: Does not work like this also:
    @RequestMapping(value = "/inventario", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: Solved by just putting all 3 jackson jars on classpath

Answer (score 0):

eighter you have remove the datatype while sending ajax request
i.e,

```
  dataType : "json"
```

or you have to produce the application/json response as below

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/inventario/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
```

it will gives the response as JSON object which is matched with ajax response dataType key.
you can use any one of them.